# how to convert my vb app to an activex web service

Tags: service

I made an app in VB that I want to turn into a web service. I've been told I can create a web service from VB.NET but how? Can I convert my app into a ASP.NET app or do I have to re-write it? Can I turn my app into an Active X control and create a active x web service?

Comment: First I thought ActiveX Web service was a joke, but then I found http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317880

Comment: That link doesn't make it less a joke, but an ActiveX is merely COM application. COM+ and DCOM (or even CORBA for that matter) is actually a binary version of what was later formalized into SOAP and Web Services. ActiveX is calling methods based on a common standard, WS is the same. Hence it is possible to "transfer" one into the other. What is less logical and certainly not needed is going from .NET back to old ActiveX and then forward again to modern WS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably good to first try to understand exactly what you want and why you need it. A web service has little to do with ActiveX or ASP.NET technologies. It is a way to call methods of your libraries using SOAP or REST (or similar) requests. Once you know what for you need it, you can decide how to set it up.

You can use all the code you currently have but only if it was designed to be used with a library in mind. That means: no interactive forms, messageboxes etc. There are other restrictions, but let's not get ahead of ourselves too much.

To get from A to B, change your code such that it compiles as a DLL lib that you can use and call from other applications. From there to a web service is then only a small step away.